# How to install vbetool on 64bit Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-installation, display

On Xubuntu I've used vbetool to turn off/on the display in my laptop, assigned to touchpad key because the display key didn't work. I now just installed Fedora 26 and want to use my script, but It seems that vbetool is not in the repository anymore. How can I install vbetool on Fedora 26?

I've tried to install from the source following this article [How to install vbetool on CentOS 6.6?](https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1420/how-to-install-vbetool-on-centos-6-6) but got warnings when running make and got an error

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libpci.a', needed by 'vbetool'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the problem by searching for libpci.a file on 64bit Fedora the file was located in `/usr/lib64/` so runing:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libpci.a /usr/local/lib/libpci.a
```

and then running make again solved the issue.

So the whole solution (based on CentOS article):

```
sudo dnf install pciutils-devel pciutils-devel-static libx86-devel
# if you have 32bit system, just remove 64 from lib
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libpci.a /usr/local/lib/libpci.a

# you can check if there are no new version 1.1 was latest when writing this
wget http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/vbetool/download/vbetool-1.1.tar.gz

tar xzvf vbetool-1.1.tar.gz
cd vbetool-1.1
./configure && make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dnf install libx86 -y 

wget http://mirror.orbit-os.com/archlinux/community/os/x86_64/vbetool-1.2.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

xz -d vbetool-1.2.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

tar -xvf vbetool-1.2.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar -C /

$ vbetool 
vbetool: Usage vbetool [[vbestate save|restore]|[vbemode set|get]|
[vgamode]|[dpms on|off|standby|suspend|reduced]|[post [romfile]]|
[bootpost]|[udevpost pciid]|[vgastate on|off]|
[vbefp panelid|panelsize|getbrightness|setbrightness|invert]]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank your for your contribution. Would you mind adding some explanation on _how_ your approach solves the problem, i.e. what mistake the OP may have made when originally trying to install the software, which your proposed solution does correctly.